# Date Column Help

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Help I help for finding a formula so that columns [Dec2022][Jan2023][Feb2023] would return a value from columns [wage]*[headcount] only if the [StartingDate] is equals to a dec 1,2022 ,jan 1, 2023,feb 1, 2023 otherwise it would return $0 or blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for Dec2022 is:
=IF(Startingdata=DATE(2022,12,1),wage*headcount,"$0")

The formula for Jan2023 is:
=IF(Startingdata=DATE(2023,1,1),wage*headcount,"$0")

The formula for Feb2023 is:
=IF(Startingdata=DATE(2023,2,1),wage*headcount,"$0")
[image]

The result is displayed as shown in the figure：
[image]

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Thank you! I had that same solution you did. It took me hours to figure out. I am having fun learning sp.